# android : create same multiple bitmaps on random positions using one bitmap object

Tags: android

i am not be able to create the same bitmap again and again on random positions.when i randomize the position the first bitmap image goes disappear and i want to display that first image too,and so on...
So just help me out to get out of this problem...

GameView.java

```
public class GameView extends View {
Bitmap ball;
Random random = new Random();
private long startTime;
private int i, j;
Context mContext;

public GameView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime > 2000) {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        i = random.nextInt(getWidth());
        j = random.nextInt(getHeight() / 2);
        Ball b = new Ball(mContext, i, j);
        canvas.drawBitmap(b.getBall(), i, j, null);


    }

    invalidate();
}
```

Ball.java

```
public class Ball {
private Bitmap ball;
Context context;
Resources res;
Canvas canvas;
private int i,j;

public Ball(Context mContext, int i, int j) {
    context = mContext;
    this.i = i;
    this.j = j;
    ball = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
            R.drawable.ic_launcher);

}

public void setBall(Bitmap ball) {
    this.ball = ball;
}
public Bitmap getBall() {
    return ball;
}
```

}

Comment: Every time `onDraw()` is called, you are handed a blank canvas. You need to track where the previous Bitmaps have been drawn, and draw them again.

Comment: how can i track the bitmaps previously drawn...
sir can u giving me the logic for that...

Comment: Every time you create a random ball, pop it into an ArrayList<Ball>. Then in onDraw(), cycle through the ArrayList<> and draw every ball.

Comment: sir,i did your logic but nothing happens
please correct the code for me ...
thanx in advance...

Comment: Hi did you get solution of this because if not i have solved the problem , let me know if you need the solution